# Jboss 7.1 log4j costume logging filter or exception

Tags: java, jboss, log4j, jboss7.x

let's start coding:

```
@Startup 
@Singleton
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
public class MyClass{

    public static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getSimpleName());

    @PostConstruct
    private void invoke() {
        LOG.info("INFO");
        LOG.warn("WARN");
        LOG.error("ERROR");
        LOG.fatal("FATAL");
        LOG.debug("DEBUG");
        LOG.trace("TRACE");
        }
}
```

and if I change:

```
     <root-logger> <level name="INFO"/>...</root-logger> to   "DEBUG" instead of "INFO"
```

I have debug console. **everything works fine.**

now I want to **change something**.

I want generally root-logger to be "INFO". but with  X.Y.Z package to be "DEBUG";

something like that, but it does not working:

```
<logger category="XXX.YYY.ZZZ" use-parent-handlers="false">
            <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
```

In the  other words. I only want to debug XXX.YYY.ZZZ package. not another packages ("INFO" for another packages). may be I need some filters or exception.

this XML **does not works because**  hierarchy order of log4j is that:

```
OFF       <------ PERMITED
FATAL     <------ PERMITED
ERROR     <------ PERMITED
WARN      <------ PERMITED
INFO      <-----  COSTUME LOGGING PERMITTED UP TO INFO (if root-logger is "INFO)
DEBUG
TRACE
ALL
```

if my root-logger is "INFO"  then have permission only to create costume logging to current package **with hierarchy  UP TO INFO**

but I need some exception or something like that.  I don't need any XML configuration file or properties file. I need only to change standlone.xml

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the `use-parent-handlers` to `false`, but you don't have any handlers installed on your logger. You need to change the value to `true` or add handlers to your logger.

Setting the `use-parent-handlers` to false only uses handlers that are attached to the specific logger. Since you don't have any handlers attached, there is no handler to log the output to.

In your example you're using the simple name of the class meaning the category is `MyClass` not the package name.

Try something like:

```xml
<logger category="MyClass">
    <level name="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

Comment: Can you give me an example, how to add handlers?

Comment: is it correct?
logger category="X.Y.Z" use-parent-handlers="false">

   <level name="DEBUG"/> 
   <handlers>
      <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
   </handlers>
</logger>

Comment: That would work, but I see no real reason to set the `use-parent-handlers` to false.

Comment: Do you have the console handler set to `DEBUG` too?